# Using MatLab to get rows whose 3rd columns have some specified string

Tags: matlab, findstr

I have a tab-delimited txt file.

It looks like

```
3   5    2011-05-30.01:22:02.558151+00
1   3    2014-01-10.16:25:20.992213+00
```

3rd column is the date column. I want to get rows whose dates are 2011-05-30 or 2011-05-31 or 2011-06-01 or 2011-06-02.

I am starting the code with

```
fid = fopen('input.txt');
input = textscan(fid, '%f %f %*s','delimiter','\t','HeaderLines',0);
```

**What I have tried**

1. I think I have to use findstr. But I could code it only when I use if statement. So the code was too slow.
2. Instead, using python, I simply replaced "-" with nothing, and then removed things after "date".

For example, I changed

```
2011-05-17.01:22:02.558151+00
```

to

```
20110517
```

Then, input.txt entirely consists only of number, no string.

So, it becomes easy to manipulate in MatLab.

So I imported that revised input.txt to MatLab.

Then I chose row with 3rd column being 20110517 or 20110518.

But this solution is tedious.

I tried the following solution but didn't work.

```
%// Read in the text file
textArray = textread('input.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');

%// Space split
spacesGone = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, ' ', 'split'), textArray, 'uni', false);

%// Extract only the dates
thirdColumn = cellfun(@(x) x{3}, spacesGone);

%// Get only the date now, not the time
splitDates = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, ' ', 'split'), thirdColumn, 'uni', false);
datesFinal = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, splitDates, 'uni', false);

%// Convert to datenum format
dateNums = datenum(datesFinal);

%// Filter
validDates = dateNums >= 734653 & dateNums <= 734656;

%// Get final dates
finalDates = textArray(validDates);
```

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions, or even using `datenum` or `datevec`?  Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I've modified the code so that it works.  I wasn't using `regexp` properly.  Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll give you a solution.  What you can do is use [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) to read in your text file.  What we will do is read in the text and each line will be placed in a single cell.  For each cell, we separate the line by spaces.  Once we do this, we can see that every 3 elements in the text is what you want.

As such, we will also subset the cell array so that we sample every 3 elements.  Once we do this, we then split the string based on the `.` to take out just the date itself.  We then use `datenum` to convert the date into a number.  When using `datenum`, 2011-05-30 or 2011-05-31 or 2011-06-01 or 2011-06-02 correspond to 734653 to 734656.  Therefore, we convert each of the dates into these numbers, then figure out which dates fall into this range.  We can then subset the original text cell array and proceed.  In other words, assuming your text file is called `text.txt`, do:

```
%// Read in the text file
textArray = textread('text.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');

%// Space split
spacesGone = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x), textArray, 'uni', false);

%// Extract only the dates
thirdColumn = cellfun(@(x) x{3}, spacesGone, 'uni', false);

%// Get only the date now, not the time
splitDates = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, '.'), thirdColumn, 'uni', false);
datesFinal = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, splitDates, 'uni', false);

%// Convert to datenum format
dateNums = datenum(datesFinal);

%// Filter
validDates = dateNums >= 734653 & dateNums <= 734656;

%// Get final dates
finalDates = textArray(validDates);
```

---

Using your example above, we get:

```
finalDates = 

  '3    2    2011-05-30.01:22:02.558151+00'
```

## Minor Note

`strsplit` only works for MATLAB R2013a and up.  If you don't have this, try using `regexp` instead.  As such, replace `strsplit` with `regexp`.  As such, this is what your code would look like:

```
%// Read in the text file
textArray = textread('text.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');

%// Space split
spacesGone = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, ' +', 'split'), textArray, 'uni', false);

%// Extract only the dates
thirdColumn = cellfun(@(x) x{3}, spacesGone, 'uni', false);

%// Get only the date now, not the time
splitDates = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, '\.', 'split'), thirdColumn, 'uni', false);
datesFinal = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, splitDates, 'uni', false);

%// Convert to datenum format
dateNums = datenum(datesFinal);

%// Filter
validDates = dateNums >= 734653 & dateNums <= 734656;

%// Get final dates
finalDates = textArray(validDates);
```

---

Some notes for you:

1. The first time I call `regexp` (storing into `spacesGone`), we are looking for any instances where they are separated by **at least** one space, and splitting based on that.  This is why there is the `+` operator, as we are looking for at least one space.
2. The second `regexp` call (storing into `splitDates`), to specify looking for a period, we need to do `\.`, as `.` denotes a wildcard character, and this is not what we want.

Comment: You wrote textread('text.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');    But since the first 2 columns are figures, shouldn't it be textread('text.txt', '&f %f %s', 'delimiter', '\n'); ??

Comment: @user3123767 - No.  I read the entire line as a string, and the `'delimiter'` flag of `'\n'` waits until we find a new line, so it takes the string before that point and places it into a new cell.  Did you even try the code yourself?  Why don't you give my code a try before commenting on how or why it doesn't work.  BTW, I never put non-working code on StackOverflow.  I **always** make sure it works before I post anything.

Comment: I ran it but I am failing. Index exceeds matrix dimension. I rewrote my question to show you how I edited it for regexp

Comment: I used this input     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-YmxNbmZiYUhxRlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3123767 - The data you gave me has a **period** in between the date and the time.  Your data has a **space**.  Obviously, my method won't work with your input and it has to be modified.  I used your input based on your post.  If you're going to change the input on me, you're gonna have to communicate that to me better.  Please figure out what format you want your text to conform to (the one in your post, or the one on your Google Drive), then get back to me.

Comment: I tried both period and space. For example, when the input has period, I wrote "regexp(x, '.', 'split')"   When the input has space, I wrote "regexp(x, ' ', 'split')"  In both cases, the code didn't work. I guess I don't know how to properly replace strsplit with regexp.

Comment: @user3123767 - My apologies.  You need to do a bit more work with `regexp`.  I'll modify my post.

Comment: @user3123767 - I have modified it.  My apologies for my oversight with `regexp`.  I had to do a bit more work.  The code now should work.  Take your data that you have placed in your post **(with the dots for the dates)**, and this should now work as expected.

Comment: I got this message: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in @(x)x{3}

Error in importer (line 8)
thirdColumn = cellfun(@(x) x{3}, spacesGone, 'uni', false);

Comment: @user3123767 Are you using your original data or the one on the Google Drive?  I used your data placed on your post and it works.  This basically works with your original date, so I'm going to stop helping you.  Good luck.

Comment: OK I see. I think you helped a lot. Thank you. And I tried with my data on my post. The same error persists. Perhaps the code didn't take into consideration the fact that the input is tab-delimited? or it's because of different MatLab version?

Comment: @user3123767 - That's interesting... let me figure that out.

Comment: @user3123767 - I just tried your data and tab delimiting the spaces.  My code still works.

Comment: This is how I see the input txt file using notepad++ by showing all the tabs and \r\n .  Is this different from what you observe?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-TzV6cWl3clRvRlU/edit?usp=sharing    The input.txt is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-UXBOOTFKRVFjNDg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3123767 - Yeah that shouldn't matter.  For each line, are you ensuring that there is a newline character at the end?  This may be where it's failing.